# Oracle 10g see which tables changed

Tags: oracle10g

I've got a vendor's software and, with their permission, access to their database. They won't take the time to show me what the program does as far as the changes to the tables. Can I somehow take a "snapshot" of a database before and after performing an action, then compare the two? Or at least see which tables have changed?

Comment: Consider using the column Num_rows from all_tables system object?  you could create a table w/ a timestamp showing counts before of all tables in the schema, then run it again with a different timestamp and minus the results.

Comment: @xQbert I'm looking for updates as well.

Comment: Enable flashback? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm

Comment: Or better yet, why not just have the transaction logging enabled and review the LOG for insert/update/delete statements executed in the window by the application user?  Work with a DBA to enable logging in your test window for the application user; you'll see very bit of SQL executed which would contain the tables involved.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, I'll try that.